# How can I activate TNT by putting it in the ground?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there some way to make that when I put TNT in the ground, it activates?

I know it can be done with a command (in vanilla), but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

see the arrangement below. when you place TNT on the obsidian block, it gets Ignited.

[image]

Comment: I believe placing a button /lever on it/on the block next to it would also trigger it.

Comment: Definitely. But obsidian is required to prevent lever/torch from breaking

Answer (score 2):

Any normal method of triggering TNT will work. So long as the source of the redstone trigger is within a 1-block radius in any direction

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
/summon primed_tnt COORDINATES
```

Replace COORDINATES with the coordinates of where you wish the TNT to explode from. You can access the coordinates by pressing F3 on your keyboard (or FN-F3 if you are using a laptop) and looking at where you want the TNT to explode. Look for where it says

```
Looking at: # # #
```

# # # are now your coordinates you need to enter into the command. So, now, we should have a command block that says:

```
/summon primed_tnt # # #
```

Activate this command block with a redstone power source and watch dirt (or stone or sand) go flying!